# Ajax toolkit HTML Editor value set on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

am using `HTML Editor` (ajax toolkit) in my asp.net application.

**Problem:** my problem is when I want to assign or set the value to `HTMLEditor` on page load but it is not working(code below).

but with the same code I can retrieve or get the value successfully.

JavaScript:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () 
   {
       document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Editor1_ctl02").contentWindow.innerHTML = "Some value from db"; 
       // not working :(
   });

   function getValue() 
   {
      var content = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Editor1_ctl02_ctl00").contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML 
      // this working perfect.
   }
   function copyText() 
   {
      document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Editor1_ctl02").contentWindow.innerHTML = "Some Value from another div"; 
      // working perfect.
   }
   </script>
```

My problem is I am not able to set the value in `HTML Editor` in document ready function. but the same way I can copy content of another div and I am able to set that text inside `HTML Editor`.

please give me suggestion how can I set the value in `HTML Editor` inside the `document.ready` event

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It could be a timing issue because the  html editor, when it loads, does have some javascript to run. You could try

```
window.setTimeout(document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Editor1_ctl02").contentWindow.innerHTML = "Some value from db",0);
```

to place your code at the end of the stack.